# Weird array issue.....need advice on this

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am reading data from an sql database and the connection happens but the following error occurs:

```
 {"Index was outside the bounds of the array."}
```

On this line:

```
 TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & sqRdr.GetValue(22) & vbCrLf
```

Please help me with this as I have counted all the columns in my table and they have turned out to be exactly (22).

Comment: What does `sqRdr.FieldCount` show?

Comment: @JonSkeet the FieldCount shows 22

Comment: You should prefer specifying the column name instead... Check my detailed answer with your Optimized code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column ordinal for the datareader is 0 based, so the 22nd column would be `sqRdr.GetValue(21)`

Comment: @Armaan: It's not clear what you mean by that, but this is the right answer. You fetch the first column with GetValue(0), the second with GetValue(1) etc up to the twenty-second column with GetValue(21).

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks found the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your Datareader should be like below to avoid this issue in a case when you have increased/decreased the number of column in future....

```
DR["ColumnName"]
```

---

**SqlDataReader's** this[string name] looks like:

```
Public Overrides Default ReadOnly Property Item(name As String) As Object
    Get
        Return Me.GetValue(Me.GetOrdinal(name))
    End Get
End Property
```

---

Below is the sample code...

```
Using con As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("YourConnection string")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim expression As String = "Parameter value"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression
    cmd.Connection = con
    Using dr As IDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                'You code like ....dr["YourColumnName"]
        If dr.Read() Then
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```